# Footnote number in a box

Tags: numbering, footnotes, box

I'm wondering if there is a built-in command which allows me to get the footnote number in a box.

E. g. the number 1 of the first footnote should be inside a square box.

Comment: `\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fbox{\arabic{footnote}}}` could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\fbox` one could achieve this (the following also reduces the padding done by `\fbox` for this, which gives better results):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\renewcommand\thefootnote
  {\begingroup\fboxsep=1pt\fbox{\arabic{footnote}}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
Some text\footnote{with a footnote}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hello @Skillmon thank you for your solution. If possible I prefer to use a built-in option

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi that is the "built in" solution. If you want a counter to be formatted in another way you redefine `\the<counter>`, that's standard LaTeX. And `\fbox` is standard LaTeX to but a frame around something. There will be nothing more built in than this.